# VirtualBox Windows XP has no local network

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

I’m trying to set up a Windows XP VirtualBox (with Oracle’s VirtualBox) yet it seems I don’t have drivers. In the guest Windows XP, the network section is empty, typing `ipconfig` in command prompt does nothing.  Apparently my install doesn’t have device manager either, so so much for that. I just want it so that I can connect the other bloody virtual machines to it, yet I haven’t got the slightest clue as to what is going on.

I have it on host-only adapter, but I believe the problem is in the guest OS, as it doesn’t have a local connection section and the networking section is blank.

Comment: I had to tick use TLS1 in internet explorer advanced settings.

Answer (score 71):

Windows XP doesn't have drivers for the Intel PRO/1000 card. Try selecting the PCNet FAST III network card instead. You can set it in the VM settings.

Comment: @WhiteMask why isn't this marked as correct answer yet? Simple, quick, working, precise. thanks.

Comment: Probably because it is not an answer that helped solve the problem?

Comment: Where are the VM settings for selecting the network card?

Comment: Found it. But I cannot change my Adapter type! It is greyed out!

Comment: If the adapter type box is greyed out, you need to shut down the VM. It can only be changed while the VM is stopped.

Comment: Should be the right answer

Comment: yep! - right answer for Windows XP - could have saved me one hour of guessing...

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve with your network adapter settings, host-only is not the correct setting for you if you actually want the VM to have a network connection outside of the host you are running it on...

I am running an XP VM with fairly recent version of Oracle VirtualBox, and my network settings are as follows (configured as Adapter 1):

Attached to: Bridged Adapter 
Name: (Here you select your host card from the dropdown)

Under Advanced:

Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973) 
Promiscuous Mode: Deny 
MAC Address: (Just hit the refresh button to the right)

Tick "Cable Connected", make sure it is checked.

Also remember to install your Guest additions: 
  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: I cannot change my Adapter type! It is greyed out!

Comment: See comment from Max Weller above: If the adapter type box is greyed out, you need to shut down the VM. It can only be changed while the VM is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Download the right driver from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18717/Network-Adapter-Drivers-for-Windows-XP-Final-Release)

Move and install the driver on your windows XP using the shared folder

Power off the machine

Configure the your adapter on NAT network

Next boot you will get the network working

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it took me a long time to find the right adapter but you have to shut down the VirtualBox machine by selecting "Power off the machine" - do not select "save the machine state" or "send the shutdown power" - to be able to access the varied list of network adapters in the Oracle VM dashboard settings. IF you don't do this, it will be greyed out and you would not be able to select anything. I had to do this each time to find the right network adapter that would finally populate..... otherwise all I had was a blank dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Intel stopped offering the drivers from their website.  You can still get it from the Internet Archive.  [Archived Download Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190807131701/https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18717/Network-Adapter-Drivers-for-Windows-XP-Final-Release)