# VirtualBox ping from ubuntu guest fails

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

On a windows 7 enterprise host (behind a proxy) I installed virtualbox with an ubuntu guest. Network setting is NAT. After configuring the proxy in the guest (/etc/environment and network manager) I can access the internet via browser but not in a terminal. Hence, I cannot install the guest additions and not update the os.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 8.8.8.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

It seems [others](https://superuser.com/questions/941797/ubuntu-14-04-virtualbox-guest-unable-to-ping-outside-world) had that problem before but no one solved it.

I can, however, ping the host from the guest successfully both by ip and hostname. Any ping from the host to external, like 8.8.8.8 doesn't work either. Only internal pings to other pc's work.

What could I else try?

Comment: Add another network interface called "Host-Only", which provides connection b/w host and guest.

Comment: Added but it doesn't change the behaviour. Access to the outside world from the guest's broswer ok but not from the terminal.