# How to setup networking for Ubuntu on virtualbox (win server 2008 R2)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

I have windows server 2008 R2 and created Ubuntu virtual machine using virtual box. Now I am trying to configure networking on it to act in the same way as real PC. I can get connection to internet when using NAT mode, but I can not access this machine from the network. So basically I want:

1. Access to internet from VM;
2. Access to internal network from VM;
3. Access to VM from internal network.

I've tried to Bridged mode both with "Local virtual area" and "My real networking adapter" and it didn't work ...

Answer (score 2):

Please view [this](https://superuser.com/questions/892729/virtualbox-windows-xp-has-no-local-network/892921#892921) post.  #EDIT: I meant, view the answers to that post...

The setup on the host machine should be similar.  The question then becomes, what kind of security constraints (firewall, mac filtering, etc.) is imposed by your host or network.

With the virtual machine running, open a terminal window, or if it is Ubuntu server, terminal is all you will have, type `ifconfig` and hit return.

This should dump your IP address and related information for eth0 (which I assume will be the only one linked to your host network card).  From inside your host OS, ping the Ubuntu IP address.

If that works, try pinging it from another machine.

If that works, and you are still unable to accomplish what you set out to do when you asked your question, the problem will not be VirtualBox-related.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've installed guest additions and it started to work

Comment: often it is something simple like that :-).  So it was the link to my older answer that helped you?  Did this also resolve your LAN access and Internet access requirements?

Comment: yes it did. I just installed guest additions and rebooted the machine.